# Generate a Map from a list using Streams with Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a *list* of `String`.

I want to store each *string* as *key* and the string's *length* as *value* in a `Map` (say `HashMap`).

I'm not able to achieve it.

```
List<String> ls = Arrays.asList("James", "Sam", "Scot", "Elich");
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

Function<String, Map<String, Integer>> fs = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> apply(String s) {
        map.put(s,s.length());
        return map;
    }
};

Map<String, Integer> nmap = ls
        .stream()
        .map(fs).
        .collect(Collectors.toMap()); //Lost here

System.out.println(nmap);
```

All strings are *unique*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to wrap each and every string with its own *map*, as the *function* you've created does.

Instead, you need to provide proper *arguments* while calling [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) :

- `keyMapper` - a function responsible for extracting a *key* from the stream element.
- `valueMapper` - a function that generates a *value* from the stream element.

Hence, you need the stream element itself to be a *key* we can use [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()), which is more descriptive than lambda `str -> str`, but does precisely the same.

```
Map<String,Integer> lengthByStr = ls.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(), // extracting a key
                String::length       // extracting a value
            ));
```

In case when the source list might contain duplicates, you need to provide the third argument - *mergeFunction* that will be responsible for resolving duplicates.

```
Map<String,Integer> lengthByStr = ls.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),   // key
                String::length,        // value
                (left, right) -> left  // resolving duplicates
            ));
```

Comment: Observation.  Would it not be better to do `(a,b)->a`  to handle duplicates.  For the same name their can't be a `highest value`.

Comment: @SUVAMROY well, he may have a good reason for doing it.  Or it may not make a difference.

Comment: @WJS That's correct. Amended.

Answer (score 1):

You said there would be no duplicate Strings.  But if one gets by you can use `distinct()` (which internally uses set) to ensure it doesn't cause issues.

- `a-> a` is a shorthand for using the stream value. Essentially a lambda that returns its argument.
- `distinct()` removes any duplicate strings

```
Map<String, Integer> result = names.stream().distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a, String::length));
```

If you want to get the length of a `String`, you can do it immediately as `someString.length()`.  But suppose you want to get a map of all the Strings keyed by a particular length.  You can do it using `Collectors.groupingBy()` which by default puts duplicates in a list.  In this case, the duplicate would be the length of the String.

- use the `length` of the string as a key.
- the value will be a `List<String>` to hold all strings that match that length.

```
List<String> names = List.of("James", "Sam", "Scot",
          "Elich", "lucy", "Jennifer","Bob", "Joe", "William");

Map<Integer, List<String>> lengthMap = names.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));

lengthMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
3=[Sam, Bob, Joe]
4=[Scot, lucy]
5=[James, Elich]
7=[William]
8=[Jennifer]
```

Comment: Along side your answer could you please provide the way to keep the names as key instead of length ?

Comment: I did.  See my first part of the answer.